# How to replace old fish installation

Tags: ubuntu, apt, fish, omf

Problem:

```
 ⚙  ~  fish --version
fish, version 2.5.0-238-ga811ae2
 ⚙  ~  echo $FISH_VERSION 
2.2.0
```

Trying to debug:

```
 ⚙  ~  exec fish
set: Invalid character “.” in variable name. Only alphanumerical characters and underscores are valid in a variable name.
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/setenv.fish (line 10):                 set -gx $v $$v
                                                                       ^
in function “setenv”
        called on line 46 of file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
        with parameter list “LANG en_US.UTF-8”

from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
        called during startup

Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
 ~  echo $FISH_VERSION 
2.5.0-238-ga811ae2
```

I installed fish 2.2 from apt. Then later installed fish 2.5 from directly the github repo. But it is still using the older fish, I am unsure what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

There's at least two problems here:

The first one is that you are still executing the old fish. The reason for that is probably that you installed the new fish into /usr/local (most likely because you installed it with `make install`, which defaults to that directory), but haven't adjusted your shell setting to point to the new one.

To confirm this, run `type -a fish`. It should show that fish is both in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin. To fix this, there are two solutions:

- Add the new fish to your /etc/shells and run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish` (as described in https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell#switching-to-fish)

or preferably

- Use [the PPA provided by the fish-shell project](https://launchpad.net/~fish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-2) and install the new fish via apt as well

---

The second issue is that `setenv` error. You probably have something like `setenv "LANG en_US.UTF-8"` (with the quotes) in your config.fish. This will produce that ugly error and will not set the variable like you want. The solution is to either

- Use `set -gx LANG en_US.UTF-8` or at least `setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8` (without quotes)

or

- Stop setting $LANG - fish since version 2.4.0 will set the locale on its own when it hasn't received one.